# combine xargs with sed to modify or change a a file

Tags: sed

I'm searching the general pattern ***_23 on the end of a line ( but not: at_23) inside a file , and than I'm trying to change all those findings to \<23>, in the same source file ( insert function is sed -i)
I'm doing :

```
egrep '[b-s u v w x y z ]+_[0-9]+$' sst_piso_top_c0.spf_typ_C | xargs...
```

but all my trying to continue with sed failed.

Can someone explain how to continue after the xargs? How should I deliver a list into sed and tell sed to process each one in the list, and change it, on the same file?

Comment: the first solution here is almost good. the problem is that * for example :   *13 digital_in_13   <--     translate to  -->     digital_\<31\>                         on the hand i cant search only the _%d%d because then it will find also: at_%d%d   which is forbidden. maybe i need to add if statment\

Comment: ok. this is what i need to do and the firtst answer of Shevek was close :       digital_in_31  =>     digital_in\<31\>                                                                digital_in_158  =>     digital_in\<158\>                                                              blabla_out_112  =>     blabla_out\<112\>                                                           I hope it is more clear now ...:-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the problem, but you only need to use `sed` for that:

```bash
$ sed -ri 's/[b-suvwxyz]+_([0-9]+)$/\\<\1>/g' sst_piso_top_c0.spf_typ_C
```

Here we are using `()` to capture that value and then `\1` to print it in the replacement section.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to combine `egrep` and `sed` since both commands will search for matches within files and either output the results (`egrep`) or act on them (`sed`), so `sed` alone will do. But for the sake of understanding why your line didn't work, I will go with your example:

Regular `egrep` output has the form `filename:matching_line` when run on multiple files and `matching_line` when run on a single file, while `sed` expects filenames only. To suppress normal `egrep` output and only print the names of files that include matches, use the `-l` option.

Also, you do not want a space in your character list (`[...]`), otherwise it will be too greedy and match more than a single word. A line that would work is:

```bash
$ egrep -l '[b-su-z]+_[0-9]+$' sst_piso_top_c0.spf_typ_C | xargs sed -ri 's/[b-su-z]+_([0-9])+$/\\<\1>/g'
```

If a compound command does not work, it's generally a good idea to run the seperate pieces by themselves and check their results. Also, error messages such as "No such file" will usually point you in the right direction (and it would be a good idea to include them in you report here).

Finally, as stated above, combining `egrep` and `sed` does not make sense. A sensible line would be

```bash
$ sed -ri 's/[b-su-z]+_([0-9])+$/\\<\1>/g' sst_piso_top_c0.spf_typ_C
```

*Update:* there was a typo in my regex, which I corrected. I also included the backreference to the numbers in the match which was originally included by zuazo. It seems more clear from the comments you wrote now that you don't want to replace the complete match with a static expression `\<23>` like I first understood it, but you want the matched number to appear in angle brackets...

Comment: but now -> :  *13 digital_in_13 translate to digital_\<31\>

Comment: the _in was disappered

Comment: the `in_` has disappeared because it matches the following part of the regular expression: `[b-su-z]+_`. It seemed from your question that this is what you wanted. If you are looking for something else, please specify more clearly - maybe using 2 or 3 example lines - what you would like to match and what not.

Comment: @meny I'll add a new answer to meet the requirements you described in your latest comments beneath the original question (being a new user I can only wirte comments underneath my own answers).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to meet the requirements you clarified in the comments beneath your question I would break things down into two parts:

1. exclude all lines that read `at_` right before the final number
2. from the remaining lines, remove the underscore at the end and enclose the number in angle brackets preceded by a backslash.

### Solution for part 1.:

This is most easily done by writing a regular expression that matches exactly what we **don't** want and then telling the calling command to ouput only those lines that do **not** match. This is most easily done with `grep`, so let's use it:

```bash
egrep -v "at_[0-9]+" sst_piso_top_c0.spf_typ_C
```

the `-v` or `--invert-match` option tells `grep`to print only non-matching lines.

### Solution for part 2.:

This is most easily done with `sed` s(ubstitute)-command:

```bash
sed -r 's/_([0-9]+)$/\\<\1\\>/g'
```

the regular expression matches underscore and a number at the end of the line. By enclosing the number part in brackets `(...)`, we can paste it with `\1` in the replacement section. The complete replacement sections consists of backslashed angle brackets enclosing our number backreference `\\<\1\\>`. The backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash `\\` because it is otherwise treated as a special escape character.

### Putting it all together:

If we pipe the output from the `egrep` command in 1. to our `sed` command from 2., the `sed` commands will use it as input stream:

```bash
egrep -v "at_[0-9]+" sst_piso_top_c0.spf_typ_C | sed -r 's/_([0-9]+)$/\\<\1\\>/g' > sst_piso_top_c0.spf_typ_C.new
```

Normally, the `sed` results would be sent to standard output, so the above line redirects them to a file (`> newfile`). Note that this filename has to be different than the one `egrep` is reading from, otherwise we would overwrite the same file that we are reading from and end up with an empty file.

Comment: Please don't forget to vote if you find this answer helpful. ;-)